# Docker-Compose - cannot intialize MySQL database with command --init-file

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have an application that I want to run in a container, and a database that I want to run in a container. I have implemented the database part like so.

```
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    command: --init-file /SCHEMA.sql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: shapeshop
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - backend
```

My initial schema for my database is in a file called **SCHEMA.sql** in the same directory as my **docker-compose** file.

I am using the

> command --init-file

configuration to setup up the databse.

When I run **docker-compose up** it fails with this error :

2021-05-14T08:20:59.320203Z 0 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/SCHEMA.sql' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

Is my command file specified correctly?

Comment: Without `volumes:` to map the host file into the container, the database startup can't see it.  You'd typically mount the SQL file into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` and the standard `mysql` image startup will execute it for you (only the first time the container starts).

Comment: so does this command --init work only on the file system within the container? I'm a bit confused by the documentation.

Comment: I was planning on going through the documentation today, to get an answer on these kind of questions.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As David Maze mentioned in the comments, you have to mount the schema file into the container.

> so does this command --init work only on the file system within the container?

yes.

You can also omit the init command entirely since the image automatically loads `.sql` dumps into the database. [From the docs](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/mysql#initializing-a-fresh-instance):

> [...] it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. [...] You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory [...].

Like this:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    # If you want to use a custom command, do it like this:
    # command: ["mysqld","--innodb-buffer-pool-size=2G"]
    volumes:
      # Persist data
      - "db_data:/var/lib/mysql"
      # Mount the schema file
      - "./SCHEMA.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/SCHEMA.sql"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: shapeshop
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - backend
    restart: always

volumes:
  db_data:
```

I've also added an volume for `/var/lib/mysql` so that when you stop and remove the container, the data is persisted.

Comment: This answer is perfect. I have done this in a number of environments over the years and it behaves exactly as described. Very thorough answer